# Can we test software developed in .Net 2.0 and 3.5 in QTP 9.2

Tags: .net, testing, qtp

We are required to test software being developed in 2.0 and 3.5 via QTP 9.2. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

.NET 2.0 and 3.5 use the same CLR and QTP 9.2 was released in 2007 (way after .NET 2.0) so yes you will be able to test .NET applications version 2.0 through to 3.5 with QTP 9.2.